# How do you set the width of the XamComboEditor popup?

Tags: silverlight, popup, width, infragistics

I want to set the width of the the popup of the XamComboEditor so that it will be wider than the control itself -- something like what is described in [an Infragistics thread](http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/p/41369/230272.aspx) for the XamWebComboEditor. I tried that, just changing the control type, but it didn't work. I explored [another option](http://blogs.infragistics.com/forums/t/50770.aspx), but didn't quite understand it.

Comment: Handling the dropdown opening/closing events and setting width changed the width of the whole control; trying to drill down to just the grid containing the popup and setting its width did the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out my [post on the matter](http://blogs.infragistics.com/forums/t/56767.aspx).
In a nutshell it finds the popup in the DropDownOpening event handler and set its width to the desired value.

Comment: Perfect! In the answer to your post it was the opened event. Other ways seemed to stretch the whole control. Thanks for directing me to the answer.